# How to check if a string request variable is wrong

Tags: java, spring, string, spring-boot, rest

I have String request parameter which its value can be "1-BB-JJ-675757" or "1-GG-94-656" etc.

I want to handle if given string in request body is wrong or not.

I created a if statement that returns error if there are no "-" in inputted string(such as "FF5544335" as;

if(!(getExVariable().contains("-")) {
return error;
}`

But what if inputted string comes as  "25-JJ-94" OR "44-BB-". How can I handle that ? Thank you.

Comment: Better to use regular expressions. Try something like ```\\d+-[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}-\\d+
``` or just ask ChatGpt to generate one for you

Answer (score 0):

To validate the structure of a String request parameter in Spring MVC you can use the `@Pattern` annotation, for example:

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public String getFoo(@RequestParam @Pattern("\w{1}-\w{2}-\w{2}-\w+") String code) {
```

[This page](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-requestparam-pathvariable) explains about validation of RequestParam and PathVariable
And [here](https://regex101.com/) you can try out regular expressions online

Answer (score -2):

To check if a string query variable is false, you need to define what "false" means in the context of your application.

1. Check for empty or null strings.
   Check if a string variable is empty or null. This may indicate that the value is incorrect or missing.
2. Validation against expected format:
   If you want a string to conform to a particular format, use regular expressions or string methods to check if the string conforms to an expected pattern.
3. Review the list of valid options.
   If a variable must belong to a predefined set of values, check whether the variable is included in that set.
4. Handle type mismatch:
   If you expect a variable to have a specific type, check its type and handle any discrepancies.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me a example on validation against expected format, thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Generative artificial intelligence (a.k.a. GPT, LLM, generative AI, genAI) tools may not be used to generate content for Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)